# Hover on tile amongst other tiles to show content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2s1tw05j/)

I am pretty new to coding so apologies for the noob question and lack of starter code!

I am looking to achieve the following  using JQuery.

If I had for instance, a row of collapsed tiles with the same styling but different content in each. What code should I do to make the tile open on hover for each tile? [image: Link to image]

The only code I have is some starter CSS and HTML code

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.tile {
  width:200px;
  padding:20px;
  background: grey;
}

.tile_content {
  height:200px;
  display:none;
}



<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please, add a snippet/jsfiddle/codepen  or at least add your relevant html fragment / js? Thanks

Comment: Added, sorry about that

Comment: please add JsFiddle link for that problem

Comment: added the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".tile").hover(function(){

// on hover over class .tile
  $(this).find(".tile_content").css("display", "block")
  //find inside class .tile_content and set display to block
  }, function(){
  $(this).find(".tile_content").css("display", "none")
  // on mouse out set it back
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.tile_header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}
.tile {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  color:white;
}

.tile_content {
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is mostly correct! although, all 3 expand when one is hovered. Is there a way to only expand the one tile that is being hovered upon?

Comment: @DonnieBerry They do not expand. Your picture and CSS you provided is not the same. Your problem was CSS; you applied background color to `.title` witch is parent of all elements, and that is what was shown. Apply background color to `.tile_header` will fix the issue. Cheek the fiddle now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't neeed js for this, just use `.tile_header:hover + .tile_content` selector to show the content when hover its header in your css then it will work as expected:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.tile_header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}
.tile {
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
  color:white;
}
.tile_content {
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  background: gray;
}
.tile_header:hover + .tile_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile_header">
      <h1>Header 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tile_content">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```